# Updating linked Excel charts in PowerPoint

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I can do this by going to file -> links -> update automatically.

However, this leads to crashes on other people's computers. This might be a compatibility issue since I'm on PowerPoint 2016.

I have 30+ charts that I would like updated.

I tried the following VBA but I end up with a pop-up from Excel saying:

> Microsoft Excel is waiting for another application to complete an OLE action.

This continued popping up for 15 minutes.

```vb
Sub ChangeChartData()
    
    Dim pptChart As Chart
    Dim pptChartData As ChartData
    Dim pptWorkbook As Object
    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim shp As Shape
    
    For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each shp In sld.Shapes
            If shp.HasChart Then
                Set pptChart = shp.Chart
                Set pptChartData = pptChart.ChartData
                pptChartData.Activate
                Set pptWorkbook = pptChartData.Workbook
                On Error Resume Next
                'update first link
                pptWorkbook.UpdateLink pptWorkbook.LinkSources(1)
                On Error GoTo 0
                pptWorkbook.Close True
            End If
        Next
    Next
    
    Set pptWorkbook = Nothing
    Set pptChartData = Nothing
    Set pptChart = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Comment: what does the popup/alert from Excel say, specifically? Can you add screenshot? What happens if you get rid of the `On Error Resume Next` statement?

Comment: file -> links -> update automatically -- generally this *shouldn't* crash per se, but if users are disconnected from the network with access to the linked files, this could be a problem. On a slow network connection, this may give the appearance of hanging/unresponsive but you usually just need to *wait* for it to fetch those files. These, among others, are reasons why OLE/embedded chart data is usually difficult and unreliable to work with.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm working from home, so I can't give an exact screenshot. However, the error message says "Microsoft Excel is waiting for another application to complete an OLE action"

Comment: @DavidZemens The user has access to the network with the linked files. User said they waited for 10-15 minutes before killing powerpoint. Unfortunately we're fetching the charts from a spreadsheet with high-frequency data and putting it into a .ppt file so that it's easier to update the ppt w/out manually recreating the ppt each time.

Comment: I've seen that prompt/warning before let me try to remember what it means...

Comment: Right and I'm not suggesting you recreate the PPT manually, but unless you need the PPT to be essentially real-time responsive to the underlying Excel, there may be better / more reliable ways to "update" the linked data.

Comment: @DavidZemens I appreciate the help! And no, I don't necessarily need the PPT to be real-time responsive. But you are right - file -> links -> automatic updates has actually rendered the file almost unusable for the other user. Even when selecting 'no' to updating the links, the user is unable to move, copy or format the charts

Comment: You have ~30 charts, do each of these refer to the *same* Excel workbook or do they each link back to a *different* Workbook? Are these workbook(s) also containing Links/External Data?

Comment: And do users have same problem if they set to UpdateLinks = Manual, and then do an "Update Now" from the File menu?

Comment: @DavidZemens Yes, they refer to the same Excel workbook. The Excel workbook itself does not contain any links, but it is pulling external data from a separate program, specifically Bloomberg and Haver DLX

Comment: The Bloomber/Haver is the culprit, I am about 100% certain on this. Is that through a COM Add-In or something like that?

Comment: @DavidZemens Sorry, I'm not sure what COM Add-Ins are, but it is an add-in installed separately for Excel.

Comment: right it's a COM add-in most likely, not an XLAM Add-In. When you open the Excel file manually, are you prompted with any sort of login requirement (or any other dialog box that requires user-input before it will update)?

Comment: @DavidZemens Nope, there's no prompt when I open the Excel file. There's only one prompt when I open the powerpoint file asking me if I would like to update the links.

Comment: OK, well unfortunately the Bloomberg Add-In is not something I have any way of debugging/troubleshooting, so I can just throw some guesses at you... what is `pptWorkbook.LinkSources(1)`? And I'm wondering if attempting to call that ~30 times in a loop is redundant, and could be contributing to the problem. Also, do you have any idea how the Bloomberg add-in works to query data? If it's attempting to *continuously* query live data, then Excel will probably be unavailable for **any** automation requests, because it's always "busy" from Bloomberg.

Comment: @DavidZemens Nope! As far as I know it's not continuously updating itself. Most of the data is quarterly, monthly or daily. At most it's just updating itself once a day (or at the end of the day). 

Honestly I have no idea what that line of code is. I got this code off of another forum and thought I'd try my luck with it.

Comment: Is this Excel 2016 _for Mac_? VBA interactions between Excel and PowerPoint are pretty much broken in this platform.

Comment: @JonPeltier Unfortunately, I'm on Windows 2016. Ironically, I made the upgrade because I was having so much trouble with Mac.

Comment: Have you tried just having `shp.LinkFormat.Update` in your `If shp.HasChart Then` block.  Worked on my presentation using your code.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I would be interested in trying is, change this:

```
On Error Resume Next
'update first link
pptWorkbook.UpdateLink pptWorkbook.LinkSources(1)
On Error GoTo 0
```

To this. (I had inquired earlier what happens if you remove `On Error Resume Next` and you never answered. As a *general* rule, you should never do that unless you are absolutely certain you know what you're doing with that, and are handling potential errors adequately, in this case you probably are not, but I don't know if there are errors).

```
'On Error Resume Next
'update first link
pptWorkbook.UpdateLink pptWorkbook.LinkSources(1)
'On Error GoTo 0
```

If that raises an error, please inform what specific error message is given.

If that doesn't raise an error, but results in the same problems, try this instead:

```
'On Error Resume Next
'update first link
pptWorkbook.UpdateLink pptWorkbook.LinkSources(1)
'On Error GoTo 0
Exit For   '### Get out of the loop
```

If, as you say, all charts are linked to same data, then I think it's safe to `Exit For` to avoid redundant calls that aren't doing anything.  Still problem, try:

```
'On Error Resume Next
'update first link
pptWorkbook.RefreshAll
'On Error GoTo 0
Exit For   '### Get out of the loop
```

Finally, and I have some suspicion that this might actually work, try this.  You've said there are no formula reference or external links (database, text, web queries, etc.) so it *shouldn't* seem necessary to do a `RefreshAll` or even `UpdateLink` seems pointless. Simply activating the chartdata worksheet and then immediately closing it seems like it should update the data in the PPT embedded Excel sheet and Chart. At least it does when I test on a non-Bloomberg file.

```
pptChartData.Activate
Set pptWorkbook = pptChartData.Workbook
'On Error Resume Next
'update first link
'pptWorkbook.UpdateLink pptWorkbook.LinkSources(1)
'On Error GoTo 0
pptWorkbook.Close True
Exit For
```

Note: again you want the `Exit For` because there is no sense in refreshing the same file 30 times.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll be trying this tomorrow and giving you an update on how things work. I'm not connected to the file atm, but I might play around with some random excel files and see what happens.

Comment: Hi. After trying the first suggestion, the macro keeps asking Excel to save the worksheet as a new file. The pop-up to save it will continue to pop up even if I save a new version of it.

Comment: No idea what would cause that behavior. Skip to the very last option and see if that works, just activate & close the workbook...

Answer (score 0):

For me worked this:

```
For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each shp In sld.Shapes
            If shp.HasChart Then
                shp.Chart.ChartData.Activate
                shp.Chart.ChartData.Workbook.UpdateLink shp.Chart.ChartData.Workbook.LinkSources(1)
                shp.Chart.ChartData.Workbook.Close True
            End If
        Next
    Next
```

i.e. not creating new variables just working with the original ones.

Answer (score 0):

I've just come across this happen today on a colleagues laptop. To solve the issue, in Excel go to File>Trust Center>Trust Center Settings>External Content select top radio button Enable all Data Connections